# Some troubleshoot on port COM9

Tags: arduino, node-red

I have a problem with my serial port, when I download my code to my arduino card everything goes well, but when I launch the node-red server, I am told that the serial port 9 access is denied, to communicate with the arduino card

Comment: Hi, Jimmy, try running the rode-red server *after* closing your arduino IDE. The latter might be blocking the communication with your arduino as you've used the serial communication to upload your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the COM port access is denied, that means another program is using it. If you are using Arduino IDE to flash the Arduino, check that the Serial Monitor is closed.